# Get only english words from a file

Tags: regex, shell, unix

I have many words [MM] in a file.

I ran this command:

```
cat file.txt | tr " " "\n"| sort | uniq  > uniq.out
```

I found that there are many chinese words and some alphanumeric and with special characters

I want to get all the words which are just english [A-Z][a-z] ONLY

```
grep -E "[A-Za-z]" uniq.out | grep -Ev "[0-9]" | less
```

The above command also matches alpha-numeric words.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks!

Comment: What about English words like *“re-elected”* and *“isn’t”*?  Your patterns miss those.  They also miss *“naïve façades”*. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
^[A-Za-z]+$
```

( Your  regex just said that it had to contain 1 a-z character for the line to count as a match)

Answer (score 0):

Why run four commands when just one alone does the job?

English is written in the Latin script.  Therefore this pulls out all the unique Latin-scripted words:

```
$ perl -CSD -nle '$seen{$1}++ || print $1 while /\b(\p{Latin}+)\b/g' input_file.utf8
```

But you’ll miss all the words with apostrophes or hyphens in them. Sure you don’t want those, too?

To actually know whether they’re valid words in English requires access to a good dictionary, plus rules for inflexions.  Otherwise you’ll get false positive like *“xyzzy”*, and suchlike.